# Save credential in Dart from Java server

Tags: java, dart

I have a Java server that consumes and produces JSON. In my Dart login form, I post to the server and the server will respond with a credential if I'm logged in (using `UUID.randomUUID()`).

Now every time I need to do something like update a user, I need to send along this credential. My concern is:

Since the Dart app is HTML and Javascript, will it be secure to save this in a Dart variable and then access it when I need to do some operation to the server? I understand that I should use HTTPS but I'm just wondering...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTPS secures just the transport between client and server. That doesn't help anything with the variable you save the value in.
If you control the server you could use a secure cookie that gets sent to the server automatically but isn't accessible from the client. 
If not you won't have much alternatives.

Comment: Unfortunately the post is to another domain using CORS filter so I don't think I can use sessions.

Comment: The user using the developer tools of the browser. Any JavaScript executed within this page. Anybody sniffing the network traffik when you don't use HTTPS.

Comment: But since dart doesn't allow inline javascript then this is as secure as any other site not using javascript? I mean another user can still use the developer and see the posts back and forth?